# How to find how many times in a row is the same value in an arrray?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have question how to make algorithm to find how many in a row is the same value in array...

My array has 3 values : null, 0-0.99 and 1

Now I need to find in array how many times in a row is THE LAST value.

f.e.

My array = `[null, null, null, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

So I have three 1s as last items in an array how to count them in code?

Comment: Take the last element, loop  back through the array, compare each element with the one, run a counter, count each time the are equal. when they stop to be equal you have what you want.

Comment: I think you can move the reactjs tag.  Also, I get that '1' is the last value.  Are you wanting to count 3 because there are three at the end, or 4 because there are four occurrences in the entire array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to count how many continuous elements starting from the last one are equal, you can loop backwards like so:

```js
let arr = [null, null, null, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
let last = arr[arr.length - 1];
let count = 1;
for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
  if(arr[i] === last){
    ++count;
  } else break;
}
console.log(count);
```

If you want the length of the longest consecutive sequence of numbers equal to the last element of the array, you can loop through the whole array and reset the counter each time the element is not equal to the last one.

```js
let arr =  [null, null, null, 1,1,1,1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
let curr = 0;
let maxLen = 1;
let last = arr[arr.length - 1];
for(const elem of arr){
  if(elem === last) maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, ++curr);
  else curr = 0;
}
console.log(maxLen);
```

Comment: this doesn't work. add 4 '1s'  after the third null you still get 3.  see answer below for correct solution

Comment: @DCR That really depends on how you interpret "how many times in a row is THE LAST value".

Comment: reread the question!  Hi I have question how to make algorithm to find how many in a row is the same value in array...

Comment: @DCR I have provided a second solution in any case.

Comment: the use of Math.max() is clever

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [null, null, null, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];

var needle = myArray[myArray.length-1];
var cnt = 0;
var oldCnt = 0;

for(let i = 0;i<=myArray.length;i++){


  if (myArray[i] == needle){      
      cnt++;   
      
  }else{
       
      if (cnt >= oldCnt)oldCnt=cnt;
      cnt = 0;  
      
  }
}


console.log(oldCnt);
```